# Push notifications for Ios in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I have configured my flutter app to send push notification for both Ios and Android using the firebase_messaging plugin. Everyting works fine on Android. On the other hand, on Ios i have a problem receiving notifications when the app is in the background. When the app is in the foreground I can see the notification being received, facilitated by a snackbar. I can also print the message in the console. However, the notifications are not appended in the system tray when the app is in the background or closed. I am pretty sure i have done the setup to the best of my knowledge to receive background notifications including adding the respective certificates.

**Xcode setup**
[image: Xcode setup screen shot]

**Firebase setup**[image: firebase screen shot]

What could i be missing or done wrong?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you ask for notification permissions on iOS? like this:

`FirebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();`

Comment: Yes i did. When i install the app on a device it actually requests for permission.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the bundle ID in your firebase app differs from your bundle ID in your iOS app but from your screenshots it seems the same. I also know that background notifications don’t really work on simulators, so maybe that’s the thing?